# Or, Ore, Awe and Oar

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, linguistics

Does everyone pronounce these the same way? (I mean all 4 words - not American vs. English)

Comment: Heck, everyone doesn't even pronounce "or" the same way.

Comment: Obviously _awe_ is pronounced different from the other three in rhotic dialects (including most American ones). There’s no difference between the other three to me.

Comment: (Certainly "awe" is pronounced differently from the others, by the majority of "native" speakers.)

Comment: (I think I pronounce "or", "ore, and "oar" just barely differently -- probably only possible to hear the difference if you're really concentrating on it, and then not very reliably.)

Comment: I think everybody pronounces *ore* and *oar* the same (although I'm sure somebody will contradict me now that I've said that). Some Americans (I used to be one of them) pronounce *or* like *are*. ([See Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/or).) And *awe* doesn't have an /r/.

Comment: And of course, since _or_ is usually unstressed, its vowel is frequently reduced, leaving just [ɚ] or [ɝ]. This does not happen with _ore_ or _oar_. (Ask yourself this out loud: is the /ɔr/ of _or_ the /ɔr/ of _horror_ or _ore_ or _oar_ or _Aurora_? Now put your tongue back in your mouth.)

Comment: Is it *really* only me who says all four - for/fore/faw/foar - the same ?

Comment: Well, if you're from Boston I suppose you might say them all the same.  Bostonians seem to have difficulty getting their R sounds in the right places.

Comment: @Dan No, the vast majority of speakers of non-rhotic dialects (which includes the majority of Brits) probably pronounce them all the same.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I thought the Great Vote for Scottish Succession failed. :)

Comment: @tchrist Even if you take out the Scots, the Northern Irelanders, and all the other northern dialects, I'd still estimate (though it is only guesstimation—I'm too lazy to go look it up) that there are more non-rhotic speakers in the UK than rhotic speakers.

Comment: @Janus Let's then not forget how those speakers with "intrusive *r*" saying *awe* before a word that starts with a vowel sound will stick "an *r* that never was" as a sandhi/liaison/joining effect between *awe* and the next word, further blurring any potential distinction.

Comment: @tchrist Indeed. I myself would probably pronounce _awe-inspiring_ and _oar-inspiring_ the same. Intrusive r’s just make life that tiny bit easier.

Comment: More Laura Norder ?;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm from NJ and have lived a host of places. I say or, oar and ore exactly the same way.  Awe has no 'r' in it.  So I don't say it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

In many parts of New England (US) the four would be indistinguishable. (But that's the only area I'm aware of.)

Comment: Plus major parts of the UK, as well as all of South Africa, Australia, and New Zealand, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from New South Wales, Australia and I pronounce all four of them the same. However, I had a few friends from Western Australia and they pronounced 'Or' and 'Oar' the same, but 'Ore' and 'Awe' differently. They pronounced 'Ore' like 'Or' but with a big emphasis on the 'e' and 'Awe' with a big emphasis on the 'w' like as if you would say 'Aww'.

Comment: How did they emphasise an e that isn't pronounced?